# My addEventListener does not work properly

Tags: javascript

The event listener works for a less than a second and then it doesn't work.

index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Javascript</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="my-form">
        <label id="lbl"></label>
        <button id="next">Next</button>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js file:

```
var myForm = document.getElementById("my-form");
var lbl = document.getElementById("lbl");
var nextBtn = document.getElementById("next");

nextBtn.addEventListener("click", displayDate);

function displayDate() {
    lbl.innerHTML = Date();
}
```

The date shows up for a less than a second, then it disappears instantly.

Comment: thats because default `type` of `button` is `submit`, hence your form is getting submitted change to `<button id="next" type="button">Next</button>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are clicking on a button element inside a form. The default button type is `submit` so:

1. The button is clicked
2. The click event is fired
3. The JS handles the click event
4. The form is submitted
5. The browser loads a new page

… and the new page doesn't have the modifications you made with client-side code.

---

There are a couple of approaches you could take here.

The simplest is **stop using a submit button**.

Add `type="button"` to the `<button>` element.

You could also prevent the default behaviour of the button (to stop it submitting the form):

```
function displayDate(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    lbl.innerHTML = Date();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to cancel the form submit

```js
var myForm = document.getElementById("my-form");
var lbl = document.getElementById("lbl");
var nextBtn = document.getElementById("next");

nextBtn.addEventListener("click", displayDate);

function displayDate() {
    
    lbl.innerHTML = Date();
}

document.getElementById('my-form').onsubmit = function() {
    return false;
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Javascript</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="my-form">
        <label id="lbl"></label>
        <button id="next">Next</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that you use a form. Upon clicking the Button you reload and so everything resets.

```
var myForm = document.getElementById("my-form");
var lbl = document.getElementById("lbl");
var nextBtn = document.getElementById("next");

nextBtn.addEventListener("click", displayDate);


myForm.addEventListener('submit', handleForm);

function handleForm(event) 
 {
 event.preventDefault();
 } 


function displayDate() 
{
 lbl.innerHTML = Date();
}
```

This prevents the submit from reloading the page.